# How do I draw video output from my secondary graphics card without setting it as the primary one?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a single monitor display, and two graphic cards on a Dell PC. I want to set one as the primary card, but I want to use it for GPU programming, and the second one to draw the video display output on my monitor. I have already tried changing it through BIOS, but it only shows which graphic card I want as the primary one, and draws the video output through that one (which I do not want). The NVidia settings panel only shows the current topology, without offering any option to alter it. Any ideas about how this can be done?

Comment: When you set one card as primary you only set it as the primary card for video output. It should not inhibit using the secondary card for processing tasks.